# Автонажатие кнопки "Сохранить"

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток.

Имеем страницу PHP, на странице форма, с инпутами, значение которых передаются другой странице нажатием кнопки сохранить.

1. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы если кнопку сохранить не жмут, она сама срабатывает после указанного мной количества секунд? (количество секунд хочется читать из переменной)?
2. Можно ли кнопку сохранить из кнопки сделать ссылкой??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function subm() {
document.forms['form1'].submit();
}
setTimeout(subm, 1000); // 1000 = 1 секунда
</script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="button" name="go" id="go" value="Submit" onclick="subm()" />
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Это может не работать в IE, например. Не проверял.

Answer (score 2):

1. Тут лучше всего будет применить JavaScript.
2. Да, можно. Опять же с JavaScript, используя атрибут onclick.

Например так:

```
<form name="formid">
<a href="#" onclick="document.formid.submit();">Поехали!</a>
</form>
```